# Playing a Video in a Modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

Are there any modals that can play youtube, vimeo, and videos uploaded to the website? I have been searching and can't find to many examples of modals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, one example is [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).**

[Here's a bunch of samples](http://fancybox.net/vimeo) for using Vimeo, you can easily change to YouTube etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a built-in modal in HTML / JS.

However to implement a modal all you need is nothing more than a full window sized div between your player and the background content (using the `z-index` style property) that prevents events from reaching the elements underneath it.